# In Reloaded, why bother delivering the 'gift' while avoiding contact?

Tags: the-matrix

In the Matrix: Reloaded, there is a gathering in the sewers where

> Smith delivers his 'gift' or, as he later refers to it, 'package', to
>  the door-keeper (called Corrupt) who passes it to Neo as requested.
>  The 'gift' is an earpiece. Meanwhile, Smith moves away, waits until
>  Neo fights with the agents, then when Neo has left, he comes back.

I can imagine some reason for not getting into a fight, he may feel that he is not ready.

But why should he bother with delivering this at all?

I imagine there should be a reason, because

> previously he used a strategy of deducing his opponents' moves and
>  waiting them in a surprise position. He may have changed but he still
>  use this strategy later 'inside the portal'.

Why did he choose to do this with the 'gift'?

Answer (score 9):

Smith delivered the earpiece because he's an old school villain, like comic and movie villains of the past that enjoyed taunting the hero while hatching their master plan for world domination.  The discarded earpiece was symbolic of Smith's newfound freedom; he was no longer taking orders.

As for the fight itself, my guess is that Smith used Neo to soften up the three  agents so that Smith could then overwrite them.  The more copies of him there were, the stronger Smith became.

Comment: Just to add to your answer, he probably also wanted to asses the upgraded agents capabilities, as well as see how much Neo's abilities had progressed since their last encounter, without "showing his hand" to either parties.

Answer (score 3):

Smith delivered the earpiece as a symbol of his freedom. He had it delivered to Neo as Neo was the one who accidentally "freed" him from the system. Also, when he delivered it, he was kinda showing off that he still could find Neo whenever he wanted, showing that he still had his "Agent powers".

Apart from having Neo soften up the agents as [Kyle mentions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45569/3267), Smith also didn't want the system's agents to know of his existence, so he waited for Neo to knock them out, and then overwrote them with ease.

Comment: ah, the notion of hiding from *the system agents* sounds true. Later one of them were surprised to see Smith. However, he recognized him. As for Neo, are you saying that it was intimidation that drove smith?

Comment: Smith wanted to intimidate Neo to some extent. Also, the system agent recognized Smith, true. But they were still genuinely surprised to see him there. So that still holds.

Comment: Smith's ego was shattered when Neo shattered him in the first movie. So when it comes to Neo, it's all personal for Smith. He is trying to show off that his powers can still get the better of Neo.